# For a twice differentiable function $f$ with $f,f^{''}>0$ on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

For a twice differentiable function $f$ with $f,f^{''}>0$ on $\mathbb{R}$ it is clear that $f^{'}$ has at most one zero by Rolles theorem. I like to find $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ , $\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x)$,$\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty} f'(x).$ How find these limits? $f'$ is strictly increasing by given conditions. What can we say about zeros of $f'?$ Must $f'$ has a zero or not? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Think of this example: $f(x) = - \ln x$.

Comment: what is domain??

Comment: i want general idea...

Comment: You see, $f''(x) \gt 0$ doesn't imply that $f'(x)$ has a zero. Consider $f(x) = e^x$.

Comment: yes ok...it will work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $f$ is convex and the graph lies above any tangent line.  If $f'(c) > 0$ for some $c$, then $f(x) \to + \infty$ as $x \to +\infty$. You should be able to examine all possible cases with this type of reasoning.

Comment: ok thanks i am trying to find limits...

Comment: In this case where $f(x) \to +\infty$ as $x \to +\infty$,  you could see the derivative diverge to $+\infty$ as with $f(x) = x^2$ or converge to a finite limit (since it is increasing) as with $f(x) = x + e^{-x}$.  In the second case $f''(x) = e^{-x} > 0$ and $f'(x) = 1 - e^{-x} \to 1$.

Answer (score 1):

I think, with these information it is not possible to make a statement about these limits. For example, take the functions $f_1(x):=e^x, f_2(x):=e^{-x}, f_3(x):=x^2+1$.
You can see that the derivative can have a zero, but doesn't have to.

What you can say: At least one of the limits $\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x), \lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ has to be $\infty$.